# How to add livy interpreter to Zeppelin running on EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin, livy

What is the simplest way to add livy interpreter to Zeppelin running on EMR cluster. What would be the right step to add to get it?

Comment: Please improve your question. There's not enough here to go on.

Comment: @Bay Did you find any simplest way?

Comment: @hayat: The simplest way is to use a custom installation of Zeppelin on the master node, and not use the EMR Zeppelin. Don't understand the reason why EMR does not provide livy interpreter by default, when it is standard installation with Zeppelin.

Comment: @Bay I found cmds to add livy interpreter in existing  EMR Zeppelin so I'm using that ,cd /usr/lib/zeppelin/bin && ./install-interpreter.sh --name livy after these cmd you have to restart Zeppelin